# Are these events independent?

Tags: independence

We flip a fair coin (independently) three times. Define the following two events:

A = "the number of tails is odd"

B = "the first coin comes up heads"

Are the events A and B independent?

I believe this is not independent.

My though process as follows with math.

The sample space for three flips is $2^3 = 8$

$S = \{ HTT,HHT,HHH,THT,TTH,HTH,TTT,THH \}$

Event A = $\{ THH,HTH,TTT,HHT \}$

Event B = $\{ HTT,HHT,HHH,HTH \}$

We need to prove $P(A \cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$

$P(A\cap B) = \frac{2}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(A)\cdot P(B) = \frac{4}{8} \cdot \frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$

Since $P(A \cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$ then events A and B are independent.

Comment: Use a *mathematical* definition of independence to resolve questions like this one.  What definition do you know?

Comment: Well I used the fact that for two events to be independent, event A must not have an effect on event B. In this case, technically the number of tails is odd does not depend on where the first coin comes up heads in 3 rolls, and the first coin coming up heads doesn't depend on the number of tails is odd.

Id like to change my stance on this question. It is independent between A and B

Comment: The phrase "have an effect on" is not a definition and does not lead to any useful way to answer your question. You need to find a real definition and apply it.  (The whole point of textbook exercises like this is to get you to work with a definition, become familiar with it, and appreciate its consequences.)

Comment: GivenPie - That's not the [*mathematical* definition of independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events). As wuber suggests, simply use the definition to resolve the question. It involves a small amount of *calculation* to check the condition. I suggest the easy way to begin is to simply list all the elementary events in the sample space.

Comment: Even if you can resolve the question without reference to the mathematical definition, doing it by using the definition is not simply make-work. You need to get used to using the mathematical definition, because often that's the only way such questions can be resolved, and if you don't know how it works, you'll be stuck. It's an important part of the tools for later work.

Comment: @whuber Ok I tried to apply math, is the way I used it correct?

Comment: @Glen_b I read up on the wiki, i edited my answer, is the way I applied the definition correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Well done!  I hope you found the information in the duplicate to be of some use.

Comment: @whuber Yes I did, I referenced that of course.